# osx pip python3 - installing packages does not create alias

Tags: python, bash, macos

I am fresh reinstalling python 2.7 (python, pip) and 3.6 (python3, pip3). However, when I installed pipenv and virtualenv for pythn3 using pip3 - the corresponding bash commands are not added, so simple things like `$ virtualenv --version`
fail.

What is going on here? can anyone help, please?

Thanks

Comment: Where is virtualenv installed? Type the bash command `pip3 show virtualenv` to see.

Comment: `MacBook-Pro-3:~usr$ pip3 show virtualenv`   
`Name: virtualenv`   
`Version: 15.1.0`   
`Summary: Virtual Python Environment builder`    
`Home-page: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/`   
`Author: Jannis Leidel, Carl Meyer and Brian Rosner`   
`Author-email: python-virtualenv@groups.google.com`   
`License: MIT`   
`Location: /Users/___/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages`   
`Requires:`    


That is where I would expect it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Python version directory, Pip installs packages to './lib/python/site-packages/' and creates the binary in './bin/'. If you install a package to your User directory with:

`pip install --user [packagename]`

the Python version directory is:

`/Users/[username]/Library/Python/[version]/`

otherwise the directory is usually:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/[version]`.

Create a symbolic link from the virtualenv binary in `/Users/[username]/Library/Python/3.6/bin/` to `/usr/local/bin/` in your path with `ln -s`:

`ln -s /Users/[username]/Library/Python/3.6/bin/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`

and you should be all set.

If you need to delete the symbolic link simply use `rm`:

`rm /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`